# Unauthenticated client is able to get jenkins crumb and trigger project build using the crumb

Tags: java, security, jenkins, continuous-integration, rest-assured

From Rest Assured I sent a get request to obtain jenkins crumb without authentication details (user and user token), I could get the crumb and used it along with project api token to trigger build for the project using post request. I have not provided the authentication details for the post request also.

My expectation is that crumb should be accessed only by valid user and only that specific user should be able to use the crumb to trigger the job.
What kind of security configuration should I do in Jenkins?

Installed Jenkins 2.401.2 in local machine as windows service.
In security configuration,
changed Authorization as "Logged-in user can do anything" and
checked the checkbox "Allow anonymous read access".
CSRF Protection setting is changed as "strict crumb issuer" and unchecked "check session id".
Generated api token for a project as "supersecret".

From Rest assured used following code to get the crumb

```
Response r = given().baseUri("http://localhost:8081")
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .log().all()
                .get("crumbIssuer/api/json");
```

I have extracted the crumb from the response to variable s and triggered build for the project with api token using following code

```
given().baseUri("http://localhost:8081").contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .basePath("/job/ExampleJenkins")
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .header("Jenkins-Crumb", s)
                                .post("/build?token=supersecret");
```

Build got triggered for the job "ExampleJenkins".
Is it possible change security setting so that only any authenticated user using code
.auth().basic("jenkinsuser","usertoken")
should be able to get the crumb and trigger the build

I tried by changing the Authorization setting to not allow Anonymous read access, then I am not able to do the job with valid user credentials also. So, please suggest correct configuration setting for my problem